# Setting both debuggerAddress and download path using selenium with chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to set both the debuggerAddress and download directory options using chromedriver webdrivermanager (5.3.2) and selenium 4.8.0. Able to setup debuggerAddress option alone and works fine but when default_directory is used it gives error. Not sure if there is an option to set and use both. Any help or suggestions

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();        
    String downloadFilepath = "/new";
    HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);  
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Error :

```
Could not start a new session. Response code 400. Message: invalid argument: entry 0 of 'firstMatch' is invalid
from invalid argument: cannot parse capability: goog:chromeOptions
from invalid argument: unrecognized chrome option: prefs 
Host info: host: 'abc-UO2kkSNTJ', ip: ''
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.6'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], debuggerAddress: 127.0.0.1:9222, extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: 
ew, profile.default_content_settings.popups: 0}}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], debuggerAddress: 127.0.0.1:9222, extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: 
ew, profile.default_content_settings.popups: 0}}}}]
```